# Send email in PHP from a google apps account

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

I was sending emails with PHP but we have just migrated all to google apps.

I have created a new user (support@xxxxxxxxxx.com) and I don't known what I have to do to send emails with it.

I am using Codeigniter with this code:

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'
    'smtp_port' => '587',
    'smtp_timeout' => '30',
    'smtp_user' => 'support@xxxxxxxxxx.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'passExample',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'newline' => '\r\n',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from("support@xxxxxxxxxx.com", "Support");
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);

$this->email->message($message);
if($this->email->send())
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    $error=$CI->email->print_debugger();
    return $error;
}
```

Any help??

---

I try to follow this link:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=es
and this
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491

And this is what I have on gmail admin panel of google apps:
[image: Google Apps admin Panel]

The password is correct because I can log in into Gmail and these are the errors:

> with port: 25 and host:aspmx.l.google.com

```
sendEmail=220 mx.google.com ESMTP 142si1984800wmg.122 - gsmtp 
hello: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [2a02:be8:1:700:4525:cbbd:7e41:9fed]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
error sending AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 503 5.5.1 bad sequence of commands 142si1984800wmg.122 - gsmtp 
from: 250 2.1.0 OK 142si1984800wmg.122 - gsmtp
to: 250 2.1.5 OK 142si1984800wmg.122 - gsmtp
data: 354  Go ahead 142si1984800wmg.122 - gsmtp
```

> SSL with port: 465 and host:smtp.gmail.com
>
> TLS with port: 587 and host:smtp.gmail.com

```
hello: F
SMTP The following errors have been found:
error sending AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
from: 
SMTP The following errors have been found:
to: 
SMTP The following errors have been found:
data: 
SMTP The following errors have been found:
You can not send mail using SMTP PHP. Your server may be configured to use this method of shipment.
```

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Comment: `$this->email->send()`?

Comment: It was working with the other hosting, I think the problem is in host and port, but maybe I need to configure something in google apps admin panel

Comment: Can you tell us the error message?  Or if there is none, share more details about the problem / undesired behavior?

Comment: You might have to authorize that server to login as that account. It has happened to me before with google.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it!

The problem is that with Codeignter 2.X it doesn't work. I download codeigniter 3 and it works for me with this configuration:

```
$config = Array(
        'useragent' => 'ermes',
        'protocol' => 'mail',
        'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'support@xxxxxxxxxxxx.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'newline' => '\r\n',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );
```

I need to change the protocol from smtp to mail and add smtp_crypto (this function is not in Codeigniter 2.X)

Also I did not make changes in my gmail configration (in google apps).

Answer (score 0):

Sending email using google app requires few steps to complete before google actually start sending the emails you ask for...

**what's the problem:**

You need to activate sending emails from unsecured sources from google.

**How to do it:**

gmail will send you an email to support@xxxxxxxxxx.com when first time you execute the code, where your required to click on activate button. After that all the emails google will forward

**Why this happens**

Sending email directly using php is generally considered as spam. so security check for 1 time is required.

Hope you get your code started working, you also need to check that your hosting has unlimited email forwarding facility.

best luck...

Comment: How can I activate it? because I did not receive any email from Google.

Comment: send 1 email through the code, and it will sedn email to the gmail id you have given in update tab

Comment: I try hundreds of times through the code and I don't receive anything... I update the post with the errors